# Cannot install PHP7.2-dev on Ubuntu 18 due to unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, php-7.2

I have Ubuntu 18 distributive, but I need install php7.2-dev for PECL extenssions.

```
mvolchkov@ias-su:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I try install php7.2-dev:

```
mvolchkov@ias-su:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev
Unresolved packages:
 php7.2-dev : Depend on: libpcre3-dev (>= 2:8.35) but will not be installed
              Depend on: libssl-dev but will not be installed
```

But it depends on: libpcre3-dev
Than I try to install libpcre3-dev, but get follow error:

```
mvolchkov@ias-su:~$ sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
 libpcre3-dev : Depend on: libpcre3 (= 2:8.39-9) но 2:8.41-4+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 will be installed
E: Impossible to resolve problems, you have held packages.
```

Comment: might be better suited for http://askubuntu.com

Comment: OK, I will copy the question there.

Comment: Anyone else stumbling upon this question can check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048568/cannot-install-php7-2-dev-on-ubuntu-18-due-to-unmet-dependencies (which is this question asked over at askubuntu)

Comment: end up using `aptitude install` instead of `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same problem to fix this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev
```

if it does not work try to force it like this:
This solution it's overkill since you will force the installation of unauthenticated packets

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev  -y --all-not authenticated
```

Comment: Use 4 spaces before a line to make it a code block, use `\`` to quote your `code` in a description line