# what is the process to install php7.2-dev extension?

Tags: php, php-7.2

I am trying to install php7.2-dev but it depends upon dependencies i have search a lot on those but can't resolve the issue.

```
sudo apt install php7.2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-dev : Depends: autoconf (>= 2.63) but it is not installable
              Depends: automake (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
              Depends: libssl-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: pkg-config but it is not installable
              Depends: shtool but it is not installable
              Depends: libtool (>= 2.4.6-0.1~) but it is not installable
              Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Similar? [Cannot install PHP7.2-dev on Ubuntu 18 due to unmet dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972198/cannot-install-php7-2-dev-on-ubuntu-18-due-to-unmet-dependencies)